# Package Manager DNF Broken

Tags: fedora, dnf

In Fedora 23, does anybody know why DNF is messing up?

```
root>dnf info       
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dnf", line 58, in <module>
    main.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 174, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 60, in main
    return _main(base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 112, in _main
    cli.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/cli.py", line 1098, in run
    self._process_demands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/cli.py", line 813, in _process_demands
    load_available_repos=lar)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 239, in fill_sack
    self._add_repo_to_sack(r)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 115, in _add_repo_to_sack
    hrepo.filelists_fn = repo.filelists_fn
TypeError: Expected a string or a unicode object
```

No other dnf commands are possible

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, removing one (most likely corrupted) .repo from /etc/yum.repos.d/ folder solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Removed all repos. It seems the were corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when setting up an Artifactory rpm repository, and as the other comments have suggested, it is related to a repository config.

If you take a look at the beginning of the _add_repo_to_sack(r) method that is throwing the error:

```
def _add_repo_to_sack(self, repo):
        repo.load()
        hrepo = repo._hawkey_repo
        hrepo.repomd_fn = repo._repomd_fn
        hrepo.primary_fn = repo._primary_fn
        hrepo.filelists_fn = repo._filelists_fn
...
```

The assignments all correspond to loading the repository configuration and metadata, preparing it for use by DNF.

I am not 100% on these, but I think:

- `hrepo.repomd_fn = repo._repomd_fn` assigns the path to the repomd.xml file
- `hrepo.primary_fn = repo._primary_fn` assigns the path to the primary.xml file
- `hrepo.filelists_fn = repo._filelists_fn` assigns the path to the filelists.xml file

After seeing this, I checked my repository repodata/repomd.xml metadata file, and noticed that it was missing an entry for "filelists" (hence the error).

I had to “Enable File List Indexing” in the JFrog Artifactory repo so that RPM metadata calculation will also include indexing the filelists.xml metadata file. Once that file was included in the repository, dnf worked just fine.